# Open trip planner internal algorthim

Tags: opentripplanner

i know this might look silly, but i am a student really need help to completely understand how the OTP works , code , classes for a school research 
any recommendation from where to start or what to read ?
really will appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

try to take a look at the documentation of OpenTripPlanner at the following link:

http://docs.opentripplanner.org/en/latest/

For the algorithms used take a look at the 'Bibliography' section.

Long story short,

OTP uses different algorithms for different problems. Most of them are Dijkstra based.